# Failing update geometry using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I have some updated waypoint in one layer that correspond to waypoints in another (the 'Master') and I have a script that is supposed to update the geometry in the 'master' from the update layer.

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()

# find the update and master layers

master = update = None
for name, layer in layers.iteritems():
    if 'wp_master' == layer.name():
        master = layer
    elif 'changed'  == layer.name():
        update = layer

update_features = {}  # indexed by feature attribute name
for f in update.getFeatures():
    update_features[f.attribute('name')] = f

# now search the master layer for the ones that have changed

master.startEditing()
for m in master.getFeatures():
    n = m.attribute('name')
    if update_features.get(n, 'none') != 'none':
        u = update_features[n]
        old = m.geometry().asPoint()
        new = u.geometry().asPoint()
        print 'master', n, old.x(), old.y()
        print 'new', n, new.x(), new.y()
        # if not m.geometry().equals( u.geometry()) :
        print 'updating', n
        print 'time', time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        m['updated'] = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        master.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({m.id(): u.geometry()})
        master.updateFeature(m)
        master.commitChanges()
        new = m.geometry().asPoint()
        print 'nex x,y ', new.x(), new.y()
```

gives this output:

```
Running mod-test.py in: /Users/rful011/src/qgis/scripts/bin
master T J B03 3 1768944.68311 5947703.25154
new T J B03 3 1768943.24096 5947702.72496
updating T J B03 3
time 2018-02-25 11:00:38
new x,y  1768944.68311 5947703.25154
Completed script: mod-test.py
```

We note that the printed geometry of the point in master is unchange

What am I missing and is there a better way of doing this without iterating over the master layer?

Comment: Did you enable editing of the layer (`master.startEditing()`) and committing the changes (`master.commitChanges()`)?

Comment: Yes and the changes to the ‘updated’ field work, it is just the geometry changes the fail. It used to work so it is odd.

Comment: I have just moved the commit inside the loop, immediately after the updateFeature call but it makes no difference.   Time to build a nice small test script.  BTW I am running this from script_runner, not that that should matter.

Comment: I tried this script with a different update layer with two features  and it worked for the *second* feature but not the first.  Weird.